# codeigniter index.php removal

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a multi city application and have the following setup for my application

This is outside the server root

```
framework
   backend
   frontend

CI_2.0.1
   system
```

Now in server root i have 2 folders to represent 2 cities

```
html
   city1
      city1.php
   city2
      city2.php
```

I need to add a rule to get rid of the .php in the url so it looks more like

http://example.in/city1/search
http://example.in/city2/search

Or a rule to completely get rid of the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

To `index.php` and some more `.htaccess` trick I use this code (CI 2):

```
# Deny OR Allow Folder Indexes.
# Since we disable access to PHP files you 
# can leave this on without worries. 
# OR better yet, create a .htaccess file in
# the dir you want to allow browsing and
# set it to +Indexes
Options -Indexes

Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # mod_rewrite rules
    RewriteEngine on

    # If a controler can't be found - then issue a 404 error from PHP
    # Error messages (via the "error" plugin)
    # ErrorDocument 403 /index.php/403/
    # ErrorDocument 404 /index.php/404/
    # ErrorDocument 500 /index.php/500/

    # Deny any people (or bots) from the following sites: (to stop spam comments)
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} nienschanz\.ru [NC,OR]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} porn\.com
    # RewriteRule .* - [F]
    # Note: if you are having trouble from a certain URL just 
    # add it above to forbide all visitors from that site.

    # You can also uncomment this if you know the IP:
    # Deny from 192.168.1.1

    # If the file is NOT the index.php file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
    # Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php/$1

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

P.S. I think that I didn't get quite clearly your problem with .php files. But if you haven't already, you'd look at [native CI routing system](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) it may solve your problem with another approach)

Comment: @kradmiy actually i have 2 apps running the 2 apps mentioned above are currently under a test setup

I use the mod rewrite rules mentioned in codeigniter and they work correctly for the main application where index.php is in the server root.

Now i have created to more folders in root city1 and city2 each of them have their own index.php files, but when i access the urls in browser they seem to redirect to the main application under root

Comment: you can configure routes to work with urls like `city/search` without having such directories on your server actually. For example if in your urls `search` segment is constant, then you may adjust `.htaccess` rules to rewrite this urls to CI index.php and pass `city/search` as a parameter in url (you'll be able to obtain this data in controller and call suitable method based on received values). `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/search/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /inde.php?uri=$1 [L]` You'll have `url` var in GET array with data supplied.

Comment: @kradmiy can i also do something like this
$routes[':any'] = 'city/switch_city'

So the router passes every url through the city controller and from there i call the respective controllers and methods

Will this work

Comment: you can do like that: define default controller to be called in `routes.php` (i think that you already have one) and define `_remap` function in it to define your own function routing rules. more there http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Comment: @kradmiy i followed your 2nd suggestion of using codeigniter native routes system and it worked perfectly $route['pune'] = 'home';
$route['pune/(:any)'] = '$1';
$route['pune/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$2';
$route['pune/(:any)/(:any)/([a-z]+)'] = '$1/$2/$3';
$route['pune/(:any)/(:any)/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = '$1/$2/$3/$4';

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with our big URL:

http://mycustomproject.com/index.php/webpages/view/my-url-title-of-the-post

The first thing that you usually do for your Codeigniter project is to remove the index.php file from the URL. To do it so, it’s really easy:

**1st step**

Add this code to your .htaccess file to your root of your project.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

After the creation of the .htaccess file your project structure will have to look like this:

website_folder/

–––– application/

–––– assets/

–––– system/

–––– user_guide/

---- .htaccess <-------------------------

–––– index.php

–––– license.txt

**2nd step**

Now go to : application/config/config.php and change the:
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

to
$config['index_page'] = '';

So now your URL will look like this:

http://mycustomproject.com/webpages/view/my-url-title-of-the-post